# Scala compile time macro, filter argument list based on (parent) type

Tags: scala, macros, types, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a method/constructor that takes a bunch of parameters. 
Using a scala macro I can ofcourse extract the Tree representing the type of those parameters.

But I cannot find out how to convert this tree to something "useful", i.e. that I can get the parent types of, check if it is a primitive, etc.

Lets say I have a concrete type `C` and if want all parameters that inherit from `C` **or** are subtypes of `Seq[C]`.

For a bit of context:

```
case cd@q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>

    // extract everything that is subtype of C or Seq[C]
    val cs = paramss.head.map {
        case q"$mods val $name: $tpt = $default" => ???
    }
```

Everything that goes in a macro should be typechecked, right? So $tpt should have a "type"?
How do I get it and what exactly do I get back?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I determine if a type inherits from Iterable and not from Map, and if a type inherits from Map

```
val iterableType = typeOf[Iterable[_]].typeSymbol
val mapType = typeOf[Map[_, _]].typeSymbol

def isIterable(tpe: Type): Boolean = tpe.baseClasses.contains(iterableType) && !isMap(tpe)
def isMap(tpe: Type): Boolean = tpe.baseClasses.contains(mapType)
```

I use this on e.g. the fields in a class's primary constructor:

```
// tpe is a Type
val fields = tpe.declarations.collectFirst {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor => m
}.get.paramss.head

val iterableFields = fields.filter(f => isIterable(f.typeSignature))
val mapFields = fields.filter(f => isMap(f.typeSignature))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This I've seen before. But it seems silly to use such an extraction method if I've already used quasiquotes to extract the significant parts of the tree. And the use of quasi-quotes is often just so much easier! And trying to use the `typeSignature` member on non item from `paramss.head` in my example fails with: "value typeSignature is not a member of ValDef"

Comment: And, curiously, elements from paramss.head have `tpt.symbol` <none>

Comment: An attempt to call c.typecheck on one of the valdefs results in a "not found: type C".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them in anger, but it looks like you're using macro annotations.

No, you get untyped annotees.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html

> macro annottees are untyped, so that we can change their signatures

Given a client:

```
package thingy

class C

@testThing class Thingy(val c: C, i: Int) { def j = 2*i }

object Test extends App {
  Console println Thingy(42).stuff
}
```

then then the macro implementation sees:

```
val t = (annottees map (c typecheck _.tree)) match {
  case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $self => ..$stats }" :: _ =>
    val p @ q"$mods val $name: ${tpt: Type} = $default" = paramss.head.head
    Console println showRaw(tpt)
    Console println tpt.baseClasses
    toEmit
}
```

where the tree has been typechecked explicitly and the type is annotated in the extraction:

```
case q"val $name: ${tpt: Type} = ???" =>
```

I realize my spelling of annotee differs from the official docs. I just can't figure out why it should be different from devotee.

Here is the toy skeleton code, for other beginners:

```
package thingy

import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

class testThing extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro testThing.impl
}

object testThing {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val toEmit = q"""{
class Thingy(i: Int) {
  def stuff = println(i)
}

object Thingy {
  def apply(x: Int) = new Thingy(x)
}
()
}"""
    def dummy = Literal(Constant(()))
    //val t = (annottees map (_.tree)) match {
    val t = (annottees map (c typecheck _.tree)) match {
      case Nil =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "No test target")
        dummy
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $self => ..$stats }" :: _ =>
        //val p @ q"$mods val $name: $tpt = $default" = paramss.head.head
        val p @ q"$mods val $name: ${tpt: Type} = $default" = paramss.head.head
        Console println showRaw(tpt)
        Console println tpt.baseClasses
        toEmit
/*
      case (classDeclaration: ClassDef) :: Nil =>
        println("No companion provided")
        toEmit
      case (classDeclaration: ClassDef) :: (companionDeclaration: ModuleDef) :: Nil =>
        println("Companion provided")
        toEmit
*/
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid test target")
        dummy
    }
    c.Expr[Any](t)
  }
}
```